# Is it possible to compile for QNX?

Tags: rust, qnx

did somebody tried to compile Rust code for QNX? I would love switching from C++ to Rust, but have to support QNX.

Compiling for Linux (same architecture) and trying to link with QNX linker causes a lot of linking issues (not sure if this makes any sense at all):

```
undefined reference to `_Unwind_Backtrace'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_DeleteException'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetDataRelBase'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetIP'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetIPInfo'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetRegionStart'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetTextRelBase'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_RaiseException'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_SetGR'
undefined reference to `_Unwind_SetIP'
undefined reference to `__errno_location'
undefined reference to `__xpg_strerror_r'
undefined reference to `fstat64'
undefined reference to `memrchr'
undefined reference to `open64'
undefined reference to `pthread_getattr_np'
undefined reference to `sigaltstack'
undefined reference to `syscall'
undefined references to `_Unwind_Resume' follow
```

Would it be feasible to port rustc to QNX with the (rather old) C/C++ compiler from QNX, or would we also need to port the LLVM used by rustc to QNX?

Comment: Did you try to build the whole stdlib? Did you ensure the qnx libc is being linked properly? Can you get a barebones no std project to build?

Comment: I tried several qcc options for linking against libc (QNX provides several ones). I neither compiled stdlib from Rust nor from QNX; which one are you referring to (Rust or QNX)?

Comment: I'm referring to rust- you almost certainly want to use cargo's [`build-std`](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/custom-target.html) feature to build Rust's stdlib for qnx.  Also, just using libcore + liballoc + libc will probably good enough if you can't get the full stdlib to build.

Comment: I managed to compile rust for Linux using `x.py` (just to ensure that I've all required tools available). Now I'm not sure how to proceed. Any suggestion like where to seek help or is there a manual how to port the compiler (which I wasn't able to find)? (I mean besides the link you've already provided: thanks!)

Comment: You don't have to build the entire toolchain- just build the standard library for the QNX target would be good enough. [This link](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/custom-target.html) has instructions on how to create a custom target and build the standard library with cargo (does require nightly).

Comment: I guess I need to understand better what the underlying problem is: I found the location where e.g. `fstat64` is called, i.e. from the file `fs.rs`. As this is a rust file and not a C file that I can compile with the QNX compiler, how can I make it compatible with QNX? Is the signature of `fstat64` wrong for QNX and I need to adjust it?

Comment: `fstat64` comes from libc, make sure that the QNX libc is being linked correctly.

Comment: Running a very simple no_std main function (only returning a value) did work (linking at running on QNX). I guess I need to figure out how to link Rusts stdlib correctly. Do you think it is still required to compile stdlib for QNX, or is this only a linker parameter issue?

Comment: libcore and liballoc should build just fine without libc. You should use target options `post-link-args` or `pre-link-args` to tell the QNX linker to link against the proper libc.

Comment: I've created a file `aarch64-unknown-qnx-gnu.json`, derived from the linux version. When trying to compile the [no_std program](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/custom-target.html) with `cargo size --target aarch64-unknown-qnx-gnu --bin app`, cargo complains with `no such subcommand: size`.
Trying to compile inside the rust source code (master), cargo reports `failed to load manifest for workspace member rust_src/src/tools/rust-installer` (I've tried it in several directories).

Comment: Rustc version is `rustc 1.57.0-nightly (c1026539b 2021-10-15)`

Comment: `cargo size` isn't a thing. Do you want `cargo build`?

Comment: Are you building your rust::c interface using the qnx header files?   `Fstat64()`, for example, takes a different `struct stat64` layout on qnx than on linux.

Comment: It seems I'm missing some information; I tried from scratch today: [rust
compiler code 9f13](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/9f13083542cb2b9fce83ed8a50238e4a6386820f),
target file `aarch64-unknown-qnx-gnu.json` created as described in [The Embedonomicon](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/embedonomicon/custom-target.html), basically a copy of AArch64-Linux, then I ran `./x.py build --target aarch64-unknown-qnx-gnu.json`. This failes
compiling `library/stdarch/crates/std_detect/src/detect/cache.rs`, and I'm not sure it even compiles for AArch64.

Comment: My plan was to build for AArch64-Linux first (no changes in compiler) and adapt the code to the libc API as soon as this compiles. Does this make sense? Should I start compiling without `--target aarch64-unknown-qnx-gnu.json`?

Answer (score 1):

There is official support for QNX in rust since 1.67.0.

See https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/platform-support/nto-qnx.html for instructions.

changelog: https://releases.rs/docs/1.67.0/